# Visually summarising a mess of directed line segments

Tags: descriptive-statistics, vector-fields, data-visualization

I have a data set of millions of directed line segments. The line segments are sequential - it's a climatic variable (sensible heat), with observed and simulated values at half-hourly intervals. I'm trying to look for patterns in how the simulation is performing. I'm looking at a scatter plot of obs vs simulation values, and linking them with line segments, (arrows indicate the direction of time). If I plot them, I just get a blurred mess that's impossible to interpret, like this:

[image: lines]

This is a subset of 10000 lines, plotted fine and at low opacity:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=Qh_obs, xend=lead(Qh_obs), y=Qh_sim, yend=lead(Qh_sim))) +
  geom_segment(size=0.1, alpha=0.2, arrow=arrow(length=unit(2, units='mm')))
```

`dput()` of the first 700 rows of data (limited by post length):

```
structure(
    list(
        Qh_sim = c( 56.401439666748, 33.9568634033203, 16.2147789001465, 0.797790050506592, -3.19529962539673, -10.3250732421875, -11.6082448959351, -21.5074787139893, -21.5963478088379, -21.4389324188232, -19.8912830352783, -18.5908279418945, -19.2523441314697, -19.663516998291, -19.1126575469971, -18.4237308502197, -16.6181221008301, -14.7601175308228, -14.5604763031006, -14.3527803421021, -14.6219816207886, -14.791407585144, -15.452392578125, -15.8962726593018, -11.9349966049194, -7.97028636932373, 12.4507570266724, 32.1654815673828, 56.9330673217773, 82.0748443603516, 110.501235961914, 138.745697021484, 150.787033081055, 161.838928222656, 172.895263671875, 184.098617553711, 187.657043457031, 192.906372070312, 193.122268676758, 192.274002075195, 179.315124511719, 164.562591552734, 163.265823364258, 161.703796386719, 133.756286621094, 105.635498046875, 97.0240097045898, 87.8632583618164, 58.3389205932617, 33.2009048461914, 23.2682571411133, 13.6356563568115, 1.51271843910217, -10.8058795928955, -18.4257907867432, -28.3294353485107, -28.5762748718262, -28.4660148620605, -27.914514541626, -28.1746997833252, -25.5984725952148, -23.8565864562988, -22.1694507598877, -20.1849479675293, -18.4765930175781, -16.7818832397461, -16.0451354980469, -15.1096048355103, -14.2665500640869, -13.1542406082153, -13.7400493621826, -14.2256927490234, -12.1078481674194, -9.62312793731689, 4.56239414215088, 19.3795871734619, 36.5501823425293, 53.1319618225098, 78.5349884033203, 102.543434143066, 124.132804870605, 149.024841308594, 168.490493774414, 186.819458007812, 196.974853515625, 206.461471557617, 190.825912475586, 173.966354370117, 169.784240722656, 163.483337402344, 170.057342529297, 177.130859375, 151.152526855469, 124.848052978516, 105.523277282715, 86.9095840454102, 65.0981750488281, 47.1053924560547, 37.6140441894531, 27.6459007263184, 11.6691846847534, -9.11263656616211, -14.4923810958862, -19.8186340332031, -19.7054214477539, -19.5380306243896, -18.5610771179199, -17.3333301544189, -15.2278394699097, -13.2510986328125, -14.3389987945557, -15.4008350372314, -15.2393169403076, -14.9772682189941, -14.7773571014404, -14.8252429962158, -14.3530769348145, -13.9949283599854, -13.7646932601929, -13.5683641433716, -10.6225557327271, -7.85287570953369, 12.7889757156372, 33.307559967041, 57.9585304260254, 82.9256896972656, 103.849281311035, 123.98851776123, 139.554504394531, 153.459365844727, 155.708465576172, 156.308456420898, 168.309158325195, 180.855041503906, 170.150848388672, 157.897567749023, 167.118728637695, 176.979385375977, 164.941528320312, 151.726623535156, 129.560562133789, 106.847137451172, 90.3653717041016, 75.2190322875977, 45.1893653869629, 17.6202545166016, 3.75747561454773, -11.4238929748535, -16.061544418335, -20.8541488647461, -24.2586994171143, -35.7491149902344, -35.0868682861328, -34.0136642456055, -36.5957374572754, -39.7278022766113, -39.645938873291, -39.4058570861816, -40.3838768005371, -41.2248229980469, -37.6026573181152, -34.7647857666016, -33.9009971618652, -33.0245132446289, -33.1246566772461, -33.1072616577148, -32.0969009399414, -30.9401035308838, -29.17529296875, -27.8960762023926, -13.3340330123901, 0.752617418766022, 22.6873798370361, 47.5203437805176, 74.8209533691406, 103.649536132812, 115.767311096191, 126.450042724609, 135.38134765625, 143.778182983398, 163.196929931641, 183.097320556641, 185.34977722168, 180.405822753906, 124.19019317627, 73.3683242797852, 45.4884719848633, 20.1036643981934, 19.8796310424805, 20.3178596496582, 47.9409942626953, 82.116943359375, 50.5893211364746, 17.9326019287109, 4.40792560577393, -12.5418739318848, -16.5327663421631, -26.3818550109863, -25.297981262207, -32.7470741271973, -29.9625682830811, -27.3131942749023, -31.2198734283447, -34.7373046875, -34.6658058166504, -33.7417755126953, -37.2075691223145, -40.8886222839355, -46.710563659668, -52.4976997375488, -52.5255432128906, -53.0547752380371, -48.5081253051758, -44.2537536621094, -38.4348182678223, -32.7230339050293, -33.1437149047852, -11.5593519210815, 7.17707252502441, 31.1563529968262, 61.0247917175293, 94.2132186889648, 128.84162902832, 163.23681640625, 195.433120727539, 224.907135009766, 252.533569335938, 284.835266113281, 366.73974609375, 348.681823730469, 47.4801063537598, 35.7033386230469, 32.492000579834, 31.093204498291, 30.0831336975098, 30.2802581787109, 24.4593544006348, 18.207691192627, 14.9354486465454, 11.197868347168, 5.82321929931641, 0.709313631057739, -7.16020011901855, -14.6854820251465, -17.6633682250977, -20.4977111816406, -22.0218677520752, -23.2031517028809, -24.2321681976318, -25.1854190826416, -24.6185817718506, -24.1337738037109, -25.1129989624023, -26.3200550079346, -26.5416431427002, -26.6869449615479, -24.7333469390869, -23.3657665252686, -22.6811752319336, -22.250675201416, -23.4151573181152, -25.0033359527588, -25.4822063446045, -25.3521099090576, -22.5521697998047, -19.9062557220459, 0.359156370162964, 19.1307563781738, 46.6757965087891, 73.7066955566406, 99.6928863525391, 124.862083435059, 143.478332519531, 161.371948242188, 170.304809570312, 178.576522827148, 189.234710693359, 198.485946655273, 194.423461914062, 190.13264465332, 160.215957641602, 151.619934082031, 161.591171264648, 148.877197265625, 125.663970947266, 102.037330627441, 71.3725280761719, 42.2232398986816, 11.3101711273193, -14.6927795410156, -23.7536239624023, -29.005350112915, -34.4212913513184, -39.6188316345215, -41.5040550231934, -48.3728713989258, -48.8165817260742, -48.9799346923828, -50.1165580749512, -50.9267501831055, -54.3669052124023, -57.5802192687988, -51.278148651123, -44.4255867004395, -48.986988067627, -52.7080307006836, -50.2299499511719, -47.8998413085938, -47.8452110290527, -47.7136764526367, -46.5966453552246, -45.263069152832, -37.7591781616211, -30.8478374481201, -13.0412464141846, 4.11979722976685, 27.2896060943604, 49.8992958068848, 76.154296875, 101.915222167969, 117.2568359375, 131.495956420898, 133.482345581055, 133.85578918457, 129.200180053711, 124.520401000977, 106.337997436523, 92.0044784545898, 83.1318511962891, 72.4165115356445, 57.5007057189941, 43.3113327026367, 43.9538612365723, 44.5803833007812, 27.2742614746094, 11.4883327484131, 4.43370151519775, -0.998961448669434, -3.06970548629761, -8.24802303314209, -14.6941070556641, -25.3609027862549, -32.1887550354004, -44.3524131774902, -45.3849296569824, -45.8836975097656, -48.1050872802734, -50.0403327941895, -49.6862258911133, -49.2051429748535, -51.0491561889648, -52.8115653991699, -47.5616111755371, -42.3858642578125, -38.9364929199219, -35.5421180725098, -38.8878860473633, -41.7323379516602, -40.4969520568848, -39.3151359558105, -39.6106414794922, -39.8548431396484, -31.7017879486084, -23.928071975708, -20.5919418334961, -17.1818447113037, -11.7402954101562, -5.85891962051392, 2.87500905990601, 13.5797090530396, 14.1692295074463, 14.7296543121338, 16.3875885009766, 17.7452526092529, 18.7800598144531, 13.3911666870117, 8.28090286254883, 8.18113803863525, 7.52940368652344, 7.14549255371094, 10.5562772750854, 14.5577230453491, 13.8216609954834, 13.217435836792, 9.38572597503662, 5.18358755111694, 0.408845901489258, -4.73907470703125, -7.31569385528564, -9.7462272644043, -14.4905166625977, -19.2358360290527, -19.185905456543, -18.7881851196289, -21.1128730773926, -23.5489654541016, -25.5899524688721, -27.6651401519775, -29.914867401123, -32.3103256225586, -29.7734184265137, -26.6699981689453, -23.005313873291, -19.2990112304688, -19.5940990447998, -19.7387142181396, -21.8078517913818, -23.0794715881348, -22.2063541412354, -21.496603012085, -20.2096099853516, -18.8994789123535, -14.8774948120117, -13.362416267395, -6.85844230651855, -0.626304984092712, 4.18258047103882, 8.86958980560303, 14.3952417373657, 19.9570331573486, 28.4349899291992, 37.2760620117188, 59.7501678466797, 83.3066635131836, 81.3329925537109, 78.6396255493164, 61.1797561645508, 42.5757102966309, 35.5590209960938, 27.8225479125977, 40.3228302001953, 53.5760040283203, 37.0363655090332, 17.6685829162598, 13.7930936813354, 9.85000133514404, -2.50773859024048, -13.975004196167, -15.1816816329956, -16.3213844299316, -17.5221652984619, -18.590892791748, -16.5226802825928, -15.3076152801514, -16.1334381103516, -16.660701751709, -17.2150802612305, -17.8384494781494, -16.1165218353271, -14.8628597259521, -14.2122831344604, -13.5532131195068, -12.678168296814, -11.8509702682495, -9.9002513885498, -8.60262680053711, -5.33623647689819, -1.83723878860474, 14.7928104400635, 33.529296875, 61.6627388000488, 91.5459594726562, 114.042625427246, 138.510818481445, 158.718765258789, 180.581832885742, 203.790466308594, 225.997695922852, 238.775192260742, 249.26042175293, 249.061386108398, 246.818420410156, 208.249237060547, 183.078033447266, 173.349914550781, 149.30908203125, 130.532318115234, 109.913215637207, 85.9337310791016, 62.1144104003906, 38.6266860961914, 14.5616312026978, 2.3201150894165, -8.46906661987305, -23.3983821868896, -31.9061298370361, -34.5052795410156, -45.4230880737305, -44.9297332763672, -44.2740020751953, -42.5427322387695, -41.5012283325195, -41.2165412902832, -40.7961463928223, -39.0608024597168, -37.2861480712891, -35.7745933532715, -34.065128326416, -32.020824432373, -30.0336456298828, -28.9353370666504, -27.7606792449951, -25.1558971405029, -22.6062679290771, -18.8992595672607, -15.2148895263672, -10.5135841369629, -5.46805810928345, 3.64776182174683, 13.4806547164917, 26.0307102203369, 38.9599380493164, 43.6987266540527, 48.1002883911133, 57.0107574462891, 65.1574325561523, 108.581703186035, 149.017120361328, 117.917793273926, 82.2609100341797, 97.5383758544922, 114.077980041504, 107.124847412109, 99.2386474609375, 94.1376495361328, 88.5065383911133, 84.6315612792969, 80.2582244873047, 59.1023597717285, 36.824836730957, 16.5506324768066, -6.58757591247559, -11.9634218215942, -16.8297290802002, -29.9632663726807, -46.4352264404297, -50.190258026123, -50.8210830688477, -52.4621200561523, -53.0918083190918, -49.7327919006348, -46.3581619262695, -46.3597717285156, -46.1371002197266, -45.037239074707, -43.5056991577148, -40.9630889892578, -38.720630645752, -36.6026611328125, -34.4607582092285, -33.6815528869629, -32.8442649841309, -28.8638534545898, -24.6911659240723, -17.9160194396973, -10.8517961502075, 1.18139290809631, 12.8555107116699, 17.1167602539062, 21.0063629150391, 17.6684036254883, 13.7457818984985, 37.46044921875, 62.0415992736816, 90.9970855712891, 119.825897216797, 109.472351074219, 97.523681640625, 119.751220703125, 142.552734375, 185.571594238281, 230.489486694336, 165.919845581055, 101.957221984863, 71.4965515136719, 19.275203704834, 18.4319801330566, 21.5707035064697, 10.680908203125, -0.568524897098541, -1.65290892124176, -2.72797632217407, -7.60702991485596, -12.224217414856, -14.9063367843628, -17.145393371582, -16.7488956451416, -16.1218643188477, -18.2663173675537, -19.5353546142578, -19.4215087890625, -19.4733543395996, -18.6313343048096, -17.8985843658447, -17.8160037994385, -17.7385425567627, -18.1197166442871, -18.1842308044434, -17.8649215698242, -17.5712966918945, -14.396632194519, -11.5873155593872, 3.78388690948486, 20.8142070770264, 27.8011417388916, 35.3277435302734, 49.1003341674805, 62.1296272277832, 52.0718383789062, 41.3623657226562, 59.2299690246582, 76.7534484863281, 94.8044204711914, 113.663482666016, 84.6353759765625, 54.8337631225586, 39.9068336486816, 27.0321559906006, 29.9495811462402, 33.498893737793, 30.1419353485107, 24.4182014465332, 13.6406497955322, -0.0817751884460449, 9.05656623840332, 19.4020538330078, 27.5970211029053, 36.5834083557129, 26.4029788970947, 15.9569606781006, 1.85423648357391, -12.4548244476318, -14.0871753692627, -14.9814357757568, -15.620020866394, -16.045597076416, -16.2016334533691, -16.580961227417, -17.1520938873291, -17.4972972869873, -17.5148601531982, -17.4890575408936, -17.1902656555176, -16.9566650390625, -16.6339950561523, -16.3293361663818, -15.9294481277466, -15.5085792541504, -13.4159259796143, -11.4598340988159, -7.95620536804199, -3.97723698616028, 9.17121124267578, 23.092601776123, 53.7364654541016, 84.3037109375, 85.9474411010742, 87.6161346435547, 114.565757751465, 144.955017089844, 151.892929077148, 157.125518798828, 127.21068572998, 95.6404190063477, 91.669303894043, 90.5523986816406, 90.8201675415039, 71.2826232910156, 66.7185440063477, 64.7154769897461, 51.2114334106445, 42.9011650085449, 34.8370513916016, 43.3580360412598, 28.1225090026855, 11.9693984985352, -0.00951856374740601, -14.7494125366211, -17.4585494995117, -20.7018413543701, -18.4236907958984, -16.4954509735107, -15.5636291503906, -14.3133592605591, -15.0822649002075, -15.6894111633301, -16.4834728240967, -17.1170406341553, -16.8290023803711, -16.7028770446777, -17.332935333252, -17.8065013885498, -18.3344459533691, -18.7632522583008, -18.7241668701172, -18.6875514984131, -16.8509616851807, -14.9226560592651, -3.77325963973999, 8.31907653808594),
        Qh_obs = c( 56.5999984741211, 78.3342056274414, 22.2999992370605, 26.1361103057861, -10.25, -5.21000003814697, -31, -23.8260860443115, -36.7000007629395, -19.5371417999268, -30.7999992370605, -12.2965908050537, -27.5, -8.68362045288086, -31.25, -9.71363639831543, -31.6000003814697, -11.530158996582, -24.4500007629395, -11.4228811264038, -20.25, -12.4035091400146, -22.6499996185303, -12.4035091400146, -25.4500007629395, -11.4983606338501, -12.3000001907349, 6.59687471389771, 28.5, 90.0666732788086, 97.3499984741211, 147, 144.5, 148.483337402344, 171.125, 188.214279174805, 189.91667175293, 192.58332824707, 192, 183.83332824707, 196, 184, 163.5, 182, 176, 161.378570556641, 134.349990844727, 117.43529510498, 73.4970550537109, 23.2749996185303, 24.25, 7, -4, -30.1999988555908, -26.25, -36.466667175293, -33.75, -32.2142868041992, -34.2999992370605, -26.0874996185303, -29.4500007629395, -24.5928554534912, -21.0499992370605, -19.8624992370605, -17.6499996185303, -13.0812501907349, -21.25, -10.5465116500854, -16.8999996185303, -7.77636384963989, -11.25, -7.61101675033569, -20.1000003814697, -7.44649124145508, -4.84999990463257, 2.33333325386047, 24.7000007629395, 21.6749992370605, 72.9499969482422, 87.4499969482422, 137, 133.25, 163.5, 165.75, 189.5, 180.33332824707, 179.375, 172.875, 172.875, 198.846160888672, 179.75, 179.75, 187.533340454102, 153.912506103516, 126.663330078125, 99.8133316040039, 69.1500015258789, 53.9031257629395, 23.2749996185303, 31.3289470672607, -9.94999980926514, -35.7999992370605, -33.3499984741211, -32.5454559326172, -43.8499984741211, -32.2142868041992, -46.5999984741211, -27.5656242370605, -30.8500003814697, -24.6052627563477, -18.7000007629395, -24.6052627563477, -26.3999996185303, -24.4375, -34.5, -23.314998626709, -33.75, -21.4720001220703, -32.9500007629395, -17.894998550415, -28.1499996185303, -14.7951211929321, -17.3999996185303, 19.0666675567627, 14.1000003814697, 63.2166633605957, 79.5, 111.75, 130, 145.630004882812, 135.5, 152.300003051758, 142, 182.142852783203, 159.5, 170.399993896484, 179, 183.58332824707, 189.5, 169.25, 135.199996948242, 102, 62.8499984741211, 77.75, 23.2999992370605, 30.8666667938232, -19.8500003814697, -21.8999996185303, -46.7999992370605, -41.75, -49.4500007629395, -32.5999984741211, -54.25, -31.1318168640137, -63.7999992370605, -33.6458320617676, -71.5, -32.5862503051758, -71.9499969482422, -33.7815780639648, -59.0999984741211, -33.1578407287598, -51.2999992370605, -34.0882339477539, -53.5999984741211, -26.1155395507812, -44.7000007629395, -28.2628574371338, -42.2999992370605, -39.8965110778809, -36.2000007629395, 23.6875, 3.09999990463257, 91.6642913818359, 64.6500015258789, 140.774993896484, 97.1999969482422, 119.233337402344, 146, 206.5, 208, 255, 228.83332824707, 235.91667175293, 148, 97.1333312988281, 64.6999969482422, 13.1000003814697, 14.3000001907349, -7.97499990463257, 47.2000007629395, 94.3166732788086, 58.7999992370605, 16.7666664123535, 15.5500001907349, -34, -5.25, -39.9928588867188, -23.5499992370605, -26.4446430206299, -30.9500007629395, -19.124137878418, -10.1000003814697, -22.2061214447021, -5.30000019073486, -24.6906967163086, -14.6000003814697, -40.1594619750977, -16.7000007629395, -39.8902740478516, -15.25, -39.9090919494629, -13.3999996185303, -41.7460517883301, -14.3999996185303, -30.9915103912354, -59.8285713195801, -64.1750030517578, -47.4166679382324, -35.375, -6.04166650772095, 19.3624992370605, 50.5583343505859, 82.7874984741211, 113.775001525879, 144.350006103516, 169.983337402344, 198.5, 209.399993896484, 231.83332824707, 191.259994506836, -10.8142852783203, -12.6999998092651, -12.2148141860962, -8.69999980926514, -11.0065212249756, -1.20000004768372, -3.79999995231628, -7, -20.2587718963623, -5.55000019073486, -21.1949996948242, -0.75, -19.9773597717285, 4.59999990463257, -16.5245761871338, 9.60000038146973, -14.6475811004639, 6.34999990463257, -12.6646156311035, 2.59999990463257, -12.2840576171875, 6.09999990463257, -11.165714263916, 6.84999990463257, -11.0586957931519, -9.10000038146973, -12.9623193740845, -44.8499984741211, -17.7016124725342, -86.0500030517578, -28.2697906494141, -103, -35.9310340881348, -100.699996948242, -35.5413780212402, -77.5, -0.6875, -30.8999996185303, 78.7111053466797, 40.5999984741211, 139.75, 128.699996948242, 223.5, 205.5, 199, 234.5, 235.91667175293, 253, 237.75, 273.5, 239.25, 238.5, 208, 178.5, 157, 112.199996948242, 125.892303466797, 24.1000003814697, -1.02999985218048, -42.7000007629395, -33.2299995422363, -62.25, -42.7312507629395, -66, -38.0642852783203, -69.1999969482422, -38.1280479431152, -78.1999969482422, -38.0437507629395, -94.8499984741211, -40.2842102050781, -70.3499984741211, -45.9287872314453, -55.5, -40.4671440124512, -71.75, -45.8935470581055, -78.6999969482422, -45.7558822631836, -91.4499969482422, -44.4485282897949, -81.6500015258789, -32.9685173034668, -63.9000015258789, -11.490909576416, -24.75, 77.9187469482422, 44.4000015258789, 66.1571426391602, 101.050003051758, 133.25, 147.5, 153.600006103516, 150, 127.650001525879, 119, 121.985717773438, 91.1999969482422, 102.599998474121, 51.1500015258789, 44.9750022888184, 31.8500003814697, 44.9750022888184, 11.8999996185303, -1.02999985218048, -16.0499992370605, -14.5749998092651, -25.2999992370605, -33.2299995422363, -30.6499996185303, -34.7999992370605, -38.8499984741211, -31.5933322906494, -30.1000003814697, -30.521053314209, -10.8500003814697, -31.8099994659424, -5.40000009536743, -31.8099994659424, -8.19999980926514, -34.0685157775879, -16.6499996185303, -32.0609741210938, -15.4499998092651, -34.8904266357422, -10.5500001907349, -35.0377769470215, -16.2000007629395, -36.5681800842285, -19.3500003814697, -41.221794128418, -17.2999992370605, -34.1255111694336, -11.1999998092651, -29.3470592498779, -14.3999996185303, -14.7120685577393, -14.3500003814697, -14.1826095581055, -10.8000001907349, -14.1826095581055, -15.6499996185303, -12.5812501907349, 64.6285705566406, 75.875, 57.957145690918, -22.7576923370361, -11.6499996185303, -28.0942306518555, -14.4499998092651, -17.7894744873047, -8.60000038146973, -17.8083324432373, -11.1999998092651, -24.7642860412598, -15.3500003814697, -29.0279998779297, -14.6499996185303, -31.8760871887207, -17.4500007629395, -38.313159942627, -19.7000007629395, -38.091667175293, -19.1499996185303, -35.7523803710938, -24.75, -34.7178573608398, -25.1499996185303, -39.1791648864746, -21.7999992370605, -40.7736854553223, -41.2333335876465, -38.0321426391602, -38.0321426391602, -38.0321426391602, -26.4500007629395, -36.2636375427246, -20.6499996185303, -33.0900001525879, -29.8678569793701, -29.3468742370605, -28.4893951416016, -28.4893951416016, -23.7383728027344, -22.2687511444092, -0.100000001490116, -10.85178565979, 9.14999961853027, -9.98571395874023, 14.5500001907349, 20.7749996185303, 32.5, 63.4333343505859, 60.7999992370605, 78.5999984741211, 62.7000007629395, 53.9888877868652, 45, 44.1777801513672, 52.4500007629395, 53.1124992370605, 42.5999984741211, 14.1149997711182, 14.3500003814697, 12.2230768203735, 4.59999990463257, -6.31276559829712, -2.09999990463257, -7.29791641235352, -7.34999990463257, -6.31276559829712, -16.2999992370605, -7.61400032043457, -13.1999998092651, -6.71354150772095, 0.899999976158142, -7.38085079193115, 4.90000009536743, -8.1519603729248, -3.40000009536743, -10.3526315689087, -18.8500003814697, -13.6254386901855, -35.7000007629395, -24.9922218322754, -40.2999992370605, -26.7756767272949, -24.5, -14.28928565979, 18.1499996185303, 63.8000030517578, 84.0999984741211, 121, 158.5, 190.600006103516, 241.5, 232.25, 259, 251.16667175293, 249, 216.125, 245.5, 220.285720825195, 192, 178.5, 135.5, 127.666664123535, 88, 63.6000022888184, 43.2000007629395, 11.2666664123535, 0.899999976158142, -14.8666658401489, -26.5499992370605, -30.4249992370605, -36.2999992370605, -16.9874992370605, -34.75, -18.1121635437012, -33.4000015258789, -20.4543476104736, -36.7999992370605, -20.7572727203369, -38.3499984741211, -18.5482959747314, -35, -19.4232959747314, -27.5499992370605, -20.2855262756348, -27.8500003814697, -18.5185718536377, -27.4500007629395, -20.2570304870605, -18.2999992370605, -21.011999130249, -4.15000009536743, -16.0035209655762, 7.69999980926514, -0.579687595367432, 27, 42.7136383056641, 54.9500007629395, 53.8875007629395, 70.8499984741211, 58.0999984741211, 122.949996948242, 166.33332824707, 99.5499954223633, 75.8166656494141, 67.0166625976562, 157, 122, 113.974998474121, 105.949996948242, 66.0833358764648, 70.6999969482422, 66.0833358764648, 33.7999992370605, -9.30000019073486, 5.30000019073486, -18.8642864227295, 0.449999988079071, -23.4473686218262, -5.19999980926514, -13.8250007629395, -12.9499998092651, -11.9074077606201, -10.5500001907349, -10.2515621185303, -2.40000009536743, -10.4654541015625, 13.1499996185303, -10.6473217010498, 28.5, -9.10673046112061, 36.5999984741211, -9.52758598327637, 39.2000007629395, -9.25483894348145, 34.5499992370605, -9.24032306671143, 28, -8.51745986938477, 29.5, -8.1985912322998, 43.0499992370605, 13.6461534500122, 48.2999992370605, 33.3083343505859, 46.5499992370605, 21.759090423584, 66.4000015258789, 58.6083335876465, 124.099998474121, 119.625, 143, 114.625, 123, 126.699996948242, 185, 235.25, 192, 105.6875, 58.4500007629395, -5.87910461425781, -13.6499996185303, 10.5700006484985, -7.65000009536743, -6.12983846664429, -7.55000019073486, -6.5319676399231, -4.19999980926514, -9.21363639831543, -6.40000009536743, -9.50185108184814, -8.5, -9.73018932342529, -14.1000003814697, -8.34899997711182, -20.0499992370605, -10.365686416626, -20.5499992370605, -12.7941179275513, -20.2999992370605, -15.5642862319946, -14.095832824707, -15.215217590332, -15.3841466903687, -18.6651153564453, -17.2799987792969, -17.8476181030273, -17.6645832061768, -7.89047622680664, -6.06333303451538, -6.27500009536743, 24.1944446563721, 37.7583351135254, 38.3590927124023, 39.9000015258789, 47.3624992370605, 60, 100.580001831055, 126.699996948242, 114.625, 61.5333366394043, 32.7125015258789, 28.9250011444092, 37.75, 39.0750007629395, 40.9500007629395, 15.8687496185303, 9.32777786254883, -7.83653831481934, -9.12333393096924, 0.764814734458923, 8.20625019073486, 23.966667175293, 17.8136367797852, 11.7437496185303, -6.75999975204468, -10.2607841491699, -10.6448974609375, -11.3418369293213, -11.4604158401489, -10.6448974609375, -10.6448974609375, -10.6448974609375, -10.1690006256104, -10.1690006256104, -8.81122493743896, -8.13617038726807, -8.13617038726807, -8.81122493743896, -10.1690006256104, -10.1690006256104, -10.6448974609375, -11.3418369293213, -9.79583263397217, -10.5319995880127, -10.235294342041, -8.89561367034912, 4.89583349227905, 22.1972217559814, 53.4650039672852, 76.5599975585938, 80.0250015258789, 84.4333343505859, 119.625, 122.275001525879, 173.5, 188.5, 122.275001525879, 103.016662597656, 129.650009155273, 119.625, 149.33332824707, 156.125, 126.5, 111.5, 75.658332824707, 35.6125030517578, 17.5642871856689, 22.0750007629395, 19.228572845459, -0.921428740024567, -12.0538463592529, -10.707407951355, -8.72075462341309, -9.83363628387451, -9.63839244842529, -10.7851858139038, -11.0480394363403, -11.7102270126343, -11.7102270126343, -13.5681819915771, -11.7102270126343, -11.7102270126343, -13.7274990081787, -15.1280488967896, -13.7274990081787, -13.7274990081787, -13.7274990081787, -13.5681819915771, -13.8348846435547, -13.7274990081787, -13.7274990081787, -13.6940479278564, -12.7714281082153, -3.11153841018677)
        ),
    .Names = c( "Qh_sim", "Qh_obs"),
    row.names = c( NA, -700L),
    class = c( "data.table", "data.frame"),
    .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x66d468>
    )
```

I'm interested in trying to visually summarise the flow of these lines. Are there any common ways of summarising this kind of information? I could just do a vector field plot, but I think I would lose some relevant information - in particular, some of the denser areas probably have multiple groups of segments. I am considering clustering the segments (using the four variables as features), and then plotting the averages, or perhaps doing a vector-field of wind-roses, but I wanted to see if there were any better ways of going about it.

Comment: If you plot them in colors that represent the direction, will you see patterns? What makes me think of this is that when there are severe storms going on, I have seen radar images on TV where the color is based on wind direction, and tornadoes can be spotted by looking for places where there is an abrupt color change.

Comment: That's a great idea. I totally forgot about using other visual variables. I suppose I might be able indicate number of elements in a cluster with line weight too.

Comment: The other thing I can think of is some type of dynamic or animated plot, with a slider that selects a narrow window in time but can be moved smoothly so that you can see how things change.

Comment: Yeah, that's also worth trying, but I'm mostly looking at a daily cycle here, and the data is at 30 minute intervals, and is 3-7 years long, so that might work, but it might be difficult to process.

Comment: Try changing the colour based on time period: eg rainbow hues, going from red -> violet over the 7 years. You can also do this by periodicity, eg different colours by month, hour, etc.

Comment: You write that you have *segments*, but in the graph you actually seem to have a *piecewise linear trajectory* (i.e., segments are all joined end-to-end)? Is that so? If yes, you may want to edit this into your question, since it may influence possible answers (which I unfortunately have no idea about).

Comment: This is a very interesting problem, but it seems to me difficult to answer well. Can you say more about the situation, the data, & your goals here? What are the data? Must subsequent segments always join end to end? Do the regions that are passed over / through matter, or only the end points? Are there cycles / seasonality in the data? If so, is that of interest or a nuisance? etc. Can you share any of the data for people to play with?

Comment: @gung: Added some example data (not the same as the original, I forgot what that was), and a bit more explanation. This data is half-hourly, so there are daily cycles, but the seasonal cycle isn't visible (700 values is only two weeks of data). Cycles are of interest.

Comment: What are they? Do you care about the places they pass over or only where they change?

Answer (score 4):

You could also split into time chunks and make facetted plots. This would help if the flow goes back and forward over itself a few times.

It may be possible to smooth the segments to get some sense of the flow too, but I think that facetting would be a first step.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to average across days, to get one or a few "average" daily cycles instead of 1,000+ individual days.

Another idea might be a 3D representation like in [Tominski, Schumann, Andrienko, and Andrienko (2012)](http://www.informatik.uni-rostock.de/~ct/pub_files/Tominski12TrajectoryVis.pdf).

Reference:

Tominski, C., Schumann, H., Andrienko, G., Andrienko, N. (2012). Stacking-based visualization of trajectory attribute data. *Visualization and Computer Graphics, IEEE Transactions on* , vol.18, no.12, pp.2565,2574, Dec. 2012. doi: 10.1109/TVCG.2012.265. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6327262&isnumber=6327196

Comment: Those are some cool plots, but they're actually dealing with 3D data that makes sense to the human conception of spatial relations (lat, long, time; although really it's only 2D: time and distance along road). I'm not sure how I'd translate that into this situation. Average daily plots are interesting, but they loose a lot of information (e.g. what happens on days with warm mornings and rainy afternoons, etc.